# Cannot get bootstrap dropdown to work with local files offline

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, drop-down-menu

so I have been looking for how to solve this and it's been over a day now.
I have bootstrap version 4.5.2 downloaded locally. I have linked it to my html page and it seems to already be working, but one thing I cannot seem to get to work is the dropdown menu. I tried it with the exact same code in bootstrap website but it doesn't seem to want to work. If anyone could help I would appreciate it very much, thank you all! Also note that when I use the cdn everything works but I want it to work offline if possible.
I will link the code below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
  
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </nav>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: For dropdown to work you need to include bootstrap.js or bootstrap.min.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were forgotten to add jquery and bootstrap js

and you should follow the sequence.
you have to add jquery first and then popper.min.js and then bootstrap.min.js

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="">

  <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
  
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown button
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: sir, I think you misunderstood  my question. I want to work with the downloaded bootstrap files that are offline on my disk. do they include all of those in the files I downloaded? Thanks again

Comment: sorry boss, I misunderstood. You should download jquery+popper and bootstrap js and need to link up with your HTML file

Comment: do you have links for those please kind sir?

Comment: You can find the bootstrap doc here, https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/introduction/ 

You must include javascript

Comment: I commented with the link, https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/introduction/

Comment: while adding those js, please maintain the sequence, otherwise it won't work

Comment: I mean  the links for the jquery and popper. I have the css and js files already.

Comment: For jquery: https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js

Comment: And Popper : https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js

Comment: awesome! Do I link them in the head or as scripts in the body? I saved them both locally so i have them in my root folder. btw Sorry I'm not up to speed with all this yet.

Comment: You can add just the end of the body. No worries, one day you will speed up

Comment: If my answer helped you then mark my answer as approved.

Comment: You kind sir just SAVED my life! Can't thank you enough.

Comment: always welcome, that was not actually a life savior. it was pretty simple.  when you will become an expert then you can understand how it was so simple.

Answer (score 1):

To make bootstrap work offline. you have to link the boostrap javascript to your project. It comes with the downloaded file. Also you have to link the dependencies.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
<!-- Your Locally downloaded bootstrap css link--!>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">

 <!-- uncomment this  if you want to check if the code is working and remember to comment in the previous link 
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous"> --!>

      <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>

      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
      
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </nav>

      <!--Dependencies--!>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <!--BOOTSTRAP Javascript LINK remember your Js comes after the dependencies link--!>
 <script src="./css/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- uncomment this and comment the previous link to check if the code works
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> --!>
    </body>
    </html>
```